# How to use featurewise_center=True together with flow_from_directory in ImageDataGenerator?

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I set the `featurewise_center = True` and then use `flow_from_directory` to set up my training and validation data in keras. However, i got the error

```
UserWarning: This ImageDataGenerator specifies `featurewise_center`, 
but it hasn't been fit on any training data. Fit it first by calling `.fit(n
numpy_data)`
```

Is there any means I can use `flow_from_directory` and then to fit the data as required ?

Answer (score 5):

`featurewise_center` transforms the images to 0 mean. This is done by using the formulae

> X = X - mean(X)

But for the `ImageDataGenerator` to do this transformation it needs to know the mean of the dataset and `fit` method on the `ImageDataGenerator` does exactly this operation of calculating these statistics.

As the [keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator) explain

> Fits the data generator to some sample data. This computes the
>   internal data stats related to the data-dependent transformations,
>   based on an array of sample data.

If the dataset can be fully loaded into the memory, we can do so by loading all the images into a numpy array and running the `fit` on it.

Sample code (RGB images of 256x256) :

```python
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image

height = width = 256 

def read_pil_image(img_path, height, width):
        with open(img_path, 'rb') as f:
            return np.array(Image.open(f).convert('RGB').resize((width, height)))

def load_all_images(dataset_path, height, width, img_ext='png'):
    return np.array([read_pil_image(str(p), height, width) for p in 
                                    Path(dataset_path).rglob("*."+img_ext)]) 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)
train_datagen.fit(load_all_images('./images/', height, width))

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        './images/',
        target_size=(height, width),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary',
        color_mode='rgb')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(1,(3,3), input_shape=(height,width,3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')

model.fit_generator(train_generator)
```

But what if the data cannot be fully loaded into memory ? One approach is to sample the images randomly from the dataset.

Normally we use `mean` of training data only to do mean normalization and use the same mean for normalization validation/test data. It will be bit tricky to do the same via the `datagenerator`.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your code but, I got "ValueError : setting an array element with a sequence" for the code 'train_datagen.fit(load_all_images(train_dir)) where under train_dir, i have four subdirectories containing 4 different classes of images. I can't figure out where is the problem. Appreciate further help.

Comment: @Mlui looks like you have images of different resolution. Rescale all images to same size. Use `return np.array(Image.open(f).convert('RGB').resize((100,100)))` to rescale images to  (100,100).